# Agent.update hangs up on timeout

Tags: phoenix-framework, elixir

I have a very basic phoenix application, that requires some data to be loaded into memory. To manage this data I initialized an `Agent` in main `lib/my_app.ex` `start/2` as usual:

```
children = [
  supervisor(MyApp.Endpoint, []),
  ...
  worker(MyApp.Api.V1.MyController, []),
]
```

In `MyApp.Api.V1.MyController` I have a lazy loader for that data:

```
def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
  data_portion = get_data_portion(id)
end

def get_data_portion(id) do
  Agent.get(__MODULE__, fn map ->
    case Map.fetch(map, id) do
      {:ok, value} -> value
      :error -> load_data_portion(id)
    end
  end)
end

def load_data_portion(id) do
  data_portion = File.cwd!
                 |> Path.join("data/portions/#{id}.yml")
                 |> YamlElixir.read_from_file
  IO.puts "BEFORE"
  # ⇓⇓⇓⇓ on this call it hangs and terminates by default timeout (5s)
  Agent.update(__MODULE__, &Map.put(&1, id, data_portion))
  IO.puts "AFTER"
  data_portion
end
```

In case it is related, my `start_link` looks like:

```
def start_link do
  Agent.start_link(fn -> %{} end, name: __MODULE__)
end
```

I am pretty sure I am missing something basic, but I can not figure out what exactly. So, my question is: **what is wrong with `Agent.update` call above**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions that you pass to `Agent.get/2`, `Agent.update/2`, and so on, are executed in the agent process, not in the caller process.

What's happening here is a kind of deadlock: you call `load_data_portion/1` inside the function you pass to `Agent.get/2`, which means **inside the agent**.

This means that `load_data_portion/1` is executed inside the agent process. In `load_data_portion/1`, you call `Agent.update/2`, but that call cannot be handled by the agent until the current function (the one passed to `Agent.get/2`) returns.

Functions you pass to `Agent.get|update|get_and_update` functions are executed "atomically" in the agent, meaning the agent cannot do anything while it's executing those functions - including handling other calls. So `Agent.update/2` is waiting on the agent to be free to handle the passed function, but that waiting step happens inside a function that's being executed by the agent itself - hence the deadlock.

You may want to use something like `Agent.get_and_update/2` so that you can always return the data you need, and load the data you don't have only if necessary.

```
def get_data_portion(id) do
  Agent.get_and_update __MODULE__, fn(map) ->
    case Map.fetch(map, id) do
      {:ok, value} ->
        {value, map}
      :error ->
        data = parse_yaml_data(id)
        {data, Map.put(map, id, data)}
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: That is it. Thank you for the great, clean and detailed answer. I finally decided to use greedy initialization on start.